# How the Pandas Dataframe and Numpy masking technique works

Tags: pandas, numpy

I'm trying to understand how the masking technique works.

I've a dataframe with some values (say one_row_incidents) some of the are not unique. By grouping them .by the duplicate index, I can get the list of items which are used only once.

`unique = df.groupby(by="Accident_Index").Accident_Index.nunique()`

At this stage, I can create a second DataFrame with unique items with a masking technique like the following:

```
import numpy as np

pos = np.flatnonzero(one_row_incidents)
unique = df.iloc[pos]
```

The above works perfectly fine, but my question is, how does this work underneath?

In exploring the `pos` object, this is a one dimension sequencial array - with no gaps - starting from 0 to the length of `unique`. Hence, I can't see where it stores the reference to the corresponding index to the original array.

Any idea?

Comment: What is one_row_incidents?

Comment: just a dataframe containing a list of values, some of them being duplicated as mentioned.

Comment: The `numpy` docs say, that flatnonzero only returns the array indices of the array (dataframe in your case) which are non-zero. And `.iloc` of pandas just returns the rows with these indices. So what you get is not a list of unique items unless your `one_row_incidents` contains zeros for all duplicates.

Comment: note `.iloc` operates on integer row positions while `.loc` works on index labels. So your version doesn't really need to access the index.

Comment: @jottbe thanks, but in looking at the content of pos, I've seen the array from 0 to length -1 as I have previously said. Not sure this makes sense.

Comment: Neither I do :-) I'd say it depends on what `one_row_incidents` contains. Could you maybe add some minimal example to reproduce the behaviour?